# Sensitivity and Specificity for multinomial logit model

Tags: prediction, multinomial-logit, sensitivity-specificity

Hi I have a question about the sensitivity and specificity.

Situation:

- I have a estimation result using multinomial logit model.
- I want to calculate the sensitivity and specificity.

Question:

- Whether the following process is problematic or not.

  1. Get the predicted choice probabilities for each outcome.
  2. Find the maximum predicted probabilities.

  (I consider the outcome having the maximum predicted probability as the predicted outcome.)

  3. Calculate the sensitivity and specificity.

Thank you for your time spent to read this question.

Answer (score 1):

Sensitivity and specificity are probabilities in backwards time and information flow form.  Thus they are suitable for a retrospective case-control study where for example you sample 100 individuals from Y=A, 100 from Y=B, and 100 from Y=C.  If you have a prospective cohort study, or in general did not sample observations on the basis of the outcome variable Y, it is appropriate only to compute measures that are consistent with the prospective design, such as P(Y | X) for different X.  This is discussed in detail [here](https://www.fharrell.com/post/backwards-probs).